# Fetch IAM Username as the output

Tags: amazon-iam

`We are running an AWS Glue job and we believe the following code snippet should return the AWS UserId from which the job is being triggered.

For ex, the following code was run with the user mmohanty

`import boto3 client = boto3.client('sts') response = client.get_caller_identity() print('User ID:', response['UserId'])`

The output is being shown as **AROA6CNCYWLF5MGCB5DF4:GlueJobRunnerSession **instead of IAM username.

The entire output of client.get_caller_identity() doesn't have any reference to IAM username.

{'UserId': 'AROA6CNCYWLF5MGCB5DF4:GlueJobRunnerSession', 'Account': '1234567', 'Arn': 'arn:aws:sts::12345678:assumed-role/xxx-GlueRole/GlueJobRunnerSession', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'bb43bd2b-4426-46b5-8457-aaaaaaa92116d', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'bb43bd2b-4426-46b5-8457-aaaaaaa2116d', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '459', 'date': 'Fri, 20 Jan 2023 17:31:27 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

Please let us know how to get IAM username instead of the cryptic userid.

We are getting cryptic Userid instead of actual IAM username.`